# Set partition-key-expression config in Kafka Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-kafka-python

I'm using [confluent's kafka python package](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python). I would like to add a configuration property to the Producer called *partition-key-expression* in spring (Java) ([See this ref for more info](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/2.1.0.RC1/multi/multi__partitioning_with_the_kafka_binder.html))

The way I'm now instantiating the producer is the following:

```
producer = confluent_kafka.Producer({
            "bootstrap.servers": <KAFKA_SERVICE_URI>,
            "topic.acks": 1
        })
```

I was wondering whether how can I add the *partition-key-expression* config property since I could not find it in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Spring properties are not part of the base Kafka Protocol, so they wouldn't be carried over to Python libraries.

Sounds like you're asking how to define a partitioner, e.g.

```
def calc_partition(key):
  """ Get the partition, based on the key """
  return 0

producer.produce(topic, value, key, partition=calc_partition(key))
```